# Start job in X minutes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, background-process, delayed-job

I am trying to run a job 3 minutes after a controller's action was executed.

I tried this, with DelayedJob:

```
# in my controller

def index
  @books = Book.all
  Delayed::Job.enqueue(ReminderJob.new(params[:user_id]))
end
```

And in the `ReminderJob.rb` file:

```
class ReminderJob < Struct.new(:user_id)
  def perform
    p "run reminder job"
    # do something
  end
  handle_asynchronously :perform, :run_at => Proc.new { 3.minutes.from_now }
end
```

However, when accessing the index page, I don't see in the logs anything, and 3 minutes later nothing happens.

What did I do wrong ? Is there another recommended way to run a task "in X minutes from now" without using `sleep` ?

Comment: Have you read [Common-problems#nothing-happens](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/wiki/Common-problems#nothing-happens)?

Comment: Why don't you use rails' built-in `ActiveJob`?

Comment: @RaVeN I couldn't find any way to say "start this job in X minutes" with activeJob. Is this possible ?

Comment: You can use `ExampleJob.set(wait: 3.minutes).perform_later(user_id)`. I wrote an answer explaining this solution.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In this case I would use rails' built in package called `ActiveJob`.
See [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html) how to setup and basic usage. You can [use delayed_job as the backend](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job#active-job).

In your case this code would work:

```
def index
  user = User.find(params[:user_id])
  ReminderJob.set(wait: 3.minutes).perform_later(user)
end
```

and your job:

```
class ReminderJob < ApplicationJob # assumes you have a /app/jobs/application_job.rb
  def perform(user)
    # do something with the user
  end
end
```